# Calculate Average state from a probability distribution in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, tensor

I have 3 states (i.e. state is a vector, vector length is 2 in this example), I have probability distribution (such as 10% state 1, 60% state 2, 30% state 3). I would like to derive a new state that is the sum of probability * state. Of cause, I will need to consider batch too.

1> calculated probability distribution, I have a batch of 4, and 3 possibilities and the distribution is defined below.

```
dist = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.6, 0.3], [0.2, 0.4, 0.4], [0.3, 0.5, 0.2], [0.3, 0.6, 0.1]])
```

2> the 3 possible states (and batch of 4). This is a tensor of shape [4, 3, 2] or [batch, 3 possible state, state values]

```
val = tf.constant([[[10.0, 5.0],[10, 5],[10,5]],[[8, 2],[8, 2],[8, 2]],[[7, 3],[9, 1],[6, 4]],[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]])
```

I would like to get a tensor of [4, 2] or [batch, state values]. In this case, the value should be

```
[
  [10*0.1 + 10*0.6 + 10*0.3, 5*0.1 + 5*0.6 + 5*0.3],
  [8*0.2 + 8*0.4 + 8*0.4, 2*0.2 + 2*0.4 + 2*0.4],
  [7*0.3 + 9*0.5 + 6*0.2, 3*0.3 + 1*0.5 + 4*0.2],
  [1*0.3 + 3*0.6 + 5*0.1, 2*0.3 + 4*0.6 + 6*0.1]
]
```

or

```
[
  [10, 5],
  [8, 2],
  [7.8, 2.2],
  [2.6, 3.6]
]
```

How could I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found. It turns out to be simple element wise mulitiplication (* or tf.multiply)

```
dist = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.6, 0.3], [0.2, 0.4, 0.4], [0.3, 0.5, 0.2], [0.3, 0.6, 0.1]])
val = tf.constant([[[10.0, 5.0],[10, 5],[10,5]],[[8, 2],[8, 2],[8, 2]],[[7, 3],[9, 1],[6, 4]],[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]])
dist.get_shape()
   TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(3)])
val.get_shape()
   TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(3), Dimension(2)])
val2 = tf.transpose(val, perm=[0, 2, 1])
val2.get_shape()
   TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])
dist2 = tf.expand_dims(dist, 1)
dist2.get_shape()
   TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(1), Dimension(3)])
c1 = val2 * dist2
c1.get_shape()
   TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])
c2 = tf.reduce_sum(c1, 2)

print(c2.eval())
[[ 10.           5.        ]
 [  8.           2.        ]
 [  7.80000019   2.20000005]
 [  2.60000014   3.5999999 ]]
```